# Display Image According to its equivalent letter using hashtable

Tags: java, android, hashtable

im having a hard time  how to display image according to its equivalent letter
as my current code wont work with array

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> images = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();       
    images.put("A"+"a",R.drawable.a);  
    images.put("B"+"b",R.drawable.b);  
    images.put("C",R.drawable.c);  
    images.put("D",R.drawable.d);  
    images.put("E",R.drawable.e);  
    images.put("F",R.drawable.f);  
    images.put("G",R.drawable.g);  
    images.put("H",R.drawable.h);  
    images.put("I",R.drawable.i);  
    images.put("J",R.drawable.j);  
    images.put("K",R.drawable.k);  
    images.put("L",R.drawable.l);  
    images.put("M",R.drawable.m);  
    images.put("N",R.drawable.n);  
    images.put("O",R.drawable.o);  
    images.put("P",R.drawable.p);  
    images.put("Q",R.drawable.q);  
    images.put("R",R.drawable.r);  
    images.put("S",R.drawable.s);  
    images.put("T",R.drawable.t);  
    images.put("U",R.drawable.u);  
    images.put("V",R.drawable.v);  
    images.put("W",R.drawable.w);  
    images.put("X",R.drawable.x);  
    images.put("Y",R.drawable.y);  
    images.put("Z",R.drawable.z);  

        //String [] search = {"A"+"a","B"+"b"};    <<< this wont work
        String search = "A"+"a";
        if(images.containsKey(search)){

            ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageResource(images.get(search));
        }
```

if i do it manually, i only get "a" or "A" as a result,
how about if i enter letter "b" or "B", what proper code will i use this time?
because i think if i continue that method, i think my code will be awkward

*edit
what i want to do now is that this code will do a one character search, then this character will search to the
res/drawable folder to its equivalent image... 
but my problem is that how to search with the other letters...
 as the code i post above... my current code only works with "a" or "A" letter

...any suggestion will be fine to improve my application

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please explain more - your question is unanswerable at present.

Comment: as sir A--C answered... i'm trying to do a one character search
this character will search to the res/drawable folder to its equivalent image... but my problem is that how to search with the other letters... as the code i post above... it only works on "a" or "A" letter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try:

```
 Collection<String> search = new HashSet<String>{
{add("Aa");
add("Bb");}
};    

        if(images.keySet().containsAll(search)){
...
```

Comment: woah it works... thanks for the reply... i'll experiment this code and deal with my problem...